# too big latex document

Tags: errors, memory

I am facing a problem again. I am using Miktex2.9 with Texnic center 2.02. The document I want to compile has almost 160000 line of code and almost 6000 pictures. The code was generated automatically with matlab. Unfortunately I am getting  the error that Tex Capacity exceeded. I have searched for this error. but couldnt find the right one for me. Does some one have idea how to cope with the problem. I am using Letex on window 32 bit system.

[image]

Comment: Above you have a runaway error. You should correct this first (and in case there are more error earlier: correct them too. The most important error is always the first one).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it could be or it could in this case be that the first error is spurious as I think you would get that combination if indeed tex hit main mem limit while parsing the argument.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Should be easy to test by commenting a bit code before the error. Or by enlarging temporarly main memory with `--extra-mem-top=...` (I think).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Mostly if the capacity is exceeded, this is because the tex code itself has an infinite loop...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

(Not really an answer, but a placeholder to narrow down the problem. Will remove when no longer needed)

---

I don't think it's explicitly a capacity problem. I just made a 6000-page PDF, where each page contained an independent copy of example-image-a.png from the `mwe` package.

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1}
\caption{1}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2}
\caption{2}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
....
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{5999}
\caption{5999}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{6000}
\caption{6000}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Files can be downloaded from [my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvqypibnur0mf30/bigdoc.zip) (roughly 40 MB).

So far tested on MacTeX 2014 and TeX Live 2013 on Windows.